# здравствуйте я хотела подключить Node.js на телеграм но при npm start выводит такая ошибка помогите пожалуйста

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram, node-modules, nodemon

```
PS D:\js\bot_telegram> npm start

> bot_telegram@1.0.0 start
> nodemon index.js        

[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json  
[nodemon] starting `node index.js index.js` 
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\js\bot_telegram\index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v19.3.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: У вас файл **D:\js\bot_telegram\index.js** существует в каталоге?

Comment: да, думаете ощибка в этом?

Comment: Судя по ошибке - да. Попробовал у себя запустить с несуществующим файлом, получил идентичную ошибку.